# ASP.NET Join Identity table to model first tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-model-first

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 5 and I'm trying to build an application in it.

I've been reading around, and experimenting with various approaches, and I've decided to go with the model first approach.

I want to use Identity for the authentication. I've figured out how to add extra fields to the AspNetUsers table, and how to link my other tables to the AspNetUsers table by adding a foreign key to the AspNetUsers table.

However, I'm struggling with how to add the UserId from AspNetUsers as a foreign key in one of the tables I made using the designer.

Can anybody give me some advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the the AspNetUser table

- Select "Add New" > "Association"
- Select the table you have created in the dropdown on the right-hand side
- Keep the checkboxes as they are
- Press "OK"